# xargs grep suggestion

Tags: grep, awk, xargs

```
grep -v "\<Swap" instruments.log | awk '{ idx=index($0, "MasterId="); masterId=substr($0, idx+length("MasterId=")+1); masterId=substr(masterId,1,index(masterId,"L")-3); print masterId; }' | xargs grep rel.log
```

I need to search each of that MasterId/output of `awk` in `rel.log` using `xargs` or something.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `while` with `read` to get a line at a time from the pipe, and feed that to `grep`.

```
grep -v "\<Swap" instruments.log | \
  awk '{ idx=index($0, "MasterId=");
    masterId=substr($0, idx+length("MasterId=")+1);
    masterId=substr(masterId,1,index(masterId,"L")-3);
    print masterId; }' |\
  while read line; do
    grep -- "$line" rel.log
  done
```

Comment: Thank you, Your solution works, what if I need to put that in a shell script? 

`grep -v "\<Swap" instruments.log | awk '{ idx=index($0, "MasterId="); masterId=substr($0, idx+length("MasterId=")+1); masterId=substr(masterId,1,index(masterId,"L")-3); print masterId; } ' | while read line; do grep "$line" rel.log done`
It is giving me `syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: There's a simpler and faster way: [use a multiline pattern](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/xargs-grep-suggestion/30516#30516).

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a multiline pattern to grep, to search a line that contains a match for any of the patterns. In other words, a multiline pattern is a disjunction of the patterns on each line.

```
print_one_pattern_per_line | grep -f - rel.log
```

Incidentally, you could simplify the print_one_pattern_per_line part. Since you're calling awk anyway, you can do the input line matching inside it. And your awk code can be written in a simpler way, using regular expression replacement to remove everything up to `MasterId=` (assuming that there's a single occurrence of `MasterId=` on each line, because your code matches the first instance while my regexp below matches the last instance).

```
<instruments.log awk '
    !/(^|[[:space:]])Swap/ {
        gsub(/.*MasterId=/, "");
        $0 = substr($0, 1, index($0, "L")-3);
        print;
    }' | grep -f - rel.log
```